# Geometry Nodes - Instances - Having problem with directions of instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I would like the instances to follow the Y axis of the mesh vertices and flow along/follow the surface. The "Align Euler to Vector" node enables alignment along the Z axis, but I cannot get the alignment on another axis. [image]

Comment: You need a vector, that points into the direction of what you call the Y axis of the mesh vertices instead of using the Normal as the *Vector* input. And you probably need to align the Y instead of the Z axis in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you want to work with an existing grid where the directions of the edges along the *X-axis* and *Y-axis* are easily separable, you can proceed as follows:

1. Use the node `Edge Vertices` and get the direction vector of each edge with the math node `Substract`.
2. Then convert these vectors to positive values so that you can compare them with the node `Compare` (*Equal Direction Vector*) and a certain other direction (*In this example I compare it with the X-axis* and an angle of $45°$, which is $\frac{\pi}{4} = 0.785$ because here it requires radians).
3. This will give you a selection, which you can additionally make switchable with the node `Switch`, as I show in this example (*You don't really need this, but it's helpful for testing*).
4. If you now convert the mesh into curves using the node `Mesh to Curve` and your selection, you will now get curves on a specific axis where the tangents have been recalculated.
5. The node `Curve to Points` will finally give you the respective rotation of each point and now you can instantiate your cubes directly at these points and use the obtained rotation.

[image]